# Load react application into angular application

Tags: reactjs, angular, web-component

I have a react and an angular application. Right now it's loaded into iframe. Is there any other way to load a react application in to a angular app?

Saw some examples of loading react component into angular. But it's a separate application. Also saw another way of using web components.

Comment: Did you check module federation. It allows combining js applications with each other. https://www.angulararchitects.io/en/aktuelles/the-microfrontend-revolution-part-2-module-federation-with-angular/